# Advantages of using a single echo statement for a php script

Tags: php, variables, coding-style

I've recently been exposed to a PHP practice of only using a single echo statement. So effectively the view is built in a view class and a function exists to return the HTML.

This is then echoed, with this being the only echo statement in the page:

```
$output_html = $obj_cars_view->get_output_html();
echo $output_html;
```

N.B cars was the first real life object I thought of and is unrelated, I'm more interested in what advantages people can identify to using this and seeing whether its worth me adopting this method.

If the only advantage is readability and its not being widely used then its counter productive as its only more readable to people who are familiar with the practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes it easier to do post-processing on the output, even if just inspection. That's possible with php's output buffering, but this is a more direct approach.

It's easier to reuse/repurpose code if output goes into a buffer instead of directly to the page. Again, built-in output-buffering can do some of this, but it's not as flexible.

Conceptually I think you can argue that a "single output" model is cleaner that something that urps out bits of html here and there, but as you note, it does come at a cost.

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to know there was an advantage over looking tidy and the post-processing on the output seems a pretty solid arguement. At least if someone asks me why I chose to adopt it I've got more than it looks nicer to back my decision up..

Comment: @Luke: The general advantage is with changing the code. You normally move away from echoes as the application changes - that's then easier with variables as w/o. However, it's more or less a style-thing. Ask those who write the code.

Answer (score 1):

Of the top of my head: there's less likelihood for accidentally sending out headers. Clarification: you avoid the 'headers already sent' error caused by, e.g.

```
echo 'foo';
// … lots of other stuff
header('Location: /'); # or session_start() or set_cookie ....
echo 'bar';
```

Downside: the user's browser will start receiving data at a later point in time (in case of large sites).

Comment: do you mean less chance of accidently printing out the method headers, as text.. [edited as i half answered my own comment]